# How to draw two-direction traffic map in small two-way street like google traffic?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making an app with some function same to Google traffic map. But I have been stuck with below problem for weeks

I have used the "Snap to roads" method of google API to match GPS data from mobile device to road while tracking routes of users. But when I display speed data, I can not find any solution to draw 2 separated lines in 2 directions on small roads.

Does anyone know how any solution?
Please give me a clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have my own solution. It's quite simple, just using coordinates system, comparing coordinates of point n and those of n-1 to get the direction before display the polylines

Answer (score 0):

Google traffics are bi-directional vector layers. The roads API does not return such data structure but the centered road vertices. One way to fake two way lines is to create a copy of the snapped geometry and shift the longitude by 0.0001 - 0.001 for every single point in that line path. And apply styles.

Comment: Actually from snap to roads method, I get all lat&long data of the road, and it's similar for both directions. Now what I want is displays speed data on that road with two polylines on both directions. With big roads, it's easy because coordinates data are different in 2 directions